# rviz2 does not display an urdf file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I have a question related to rviz2. I am trying to display an urdf and rviz2 show this:

[image: image description]

I got the **tf** but I can't represent the 3D models.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384022/rviz2-does-not-display-an-urdf-file/) by [jarain78](https://answers.ros.org/users/36067/jarain78/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2021-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you're using the `robot_state_publisher` package to publish your TFs, it also publishes the contents of the URDF file of the robot you're using to a topic `robot_description`.

In RViz, in the Displays panel, open up **RobotModel**, and change `Description Topic` to `/robot_description`. (This makes the RobotModel visualization in RViz listen to the model of the robot from the robot_state_publisher).

Also, make sure `Visual Enabled` is ticked under Robot Model.

You should be able to see your own robot, like below (or whatever robot you're using)

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) with karma: 460 on 2021-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abubakar](https://answers.ros.org/users/110519/abubakar/) on 2022-07-13**:
Hello ijnek, I also have the same problem and I tried as you mentioned above but still no robot showed up
do you have any idea where I might be wrong

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-07-14**:
@Abubakar Would you be able to post a new question (with more details) in ROS Answers and post a link here?

**Comment by [Abubakar](https://answers.ros.org/users/110519/abubakar/) on 2022-07-14**:
It's ok ijnek the problem was solved the robot did show up but it was very small that i couldn't spot initially